# swift3 String.range(of: returns nil

Tags: string, swift3, range

The "myDRange" statement will return a range if there isn't a decimal in the value.  If there is a decimal, it will return nil.  The other statements return ranges as expected.  What am I doing wrong?

Swift3 - myDRange returns nil

```
var pseudoXML = "<d>4.0</d><rs>Test</rs><o>0</o>"
let myDRange = pseudoXML.range(of: "(?<=<d>)[^.]+(?=</d>)", options: .regularExpression)
let myRSRange = pseudoXML.range(of: "(?<=<rs>)[^.]+(?=</rs>)", options: .regularExpression)
let myORange = pseudoXML.range(of: "(?<=<o>)[^.]+(?=</o>)", options: .regularExpression)
```

Swift3 - myDRange returns a range

```
var pseudoXML = "<d>40</d><rs>Test</rs><o>0</o>"
let myDRange = pseudoXML.range(of: "(?<=<d>)[^.]+(?=</d>)", options: .regularExpression)
let myRSRange = pseudoXML.range(of: "(?<=<rs>)[^.]+(?=</rs>)", options: .regularExpression)
let myORange = pseudoXML.range(of: "(?<=<o>)[^.]+(?=</o>)", options: .regularExpression)
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CMan ,

For your `myDRange` needs to work , use below Regex "`(?<=<d>)([0-9](\\.[0-9]))+(?=</d>)`"

This will fix your nil issue for  `myDRange`

Sample of your working code :

```
var pseudoXML = "<d>4.0</d><rs>Test</rs><o>0</o>"
let myDRange = pseudoXML.range(of: "(?<=<d>)([0-9](\\.[0-9]))+(?=</d>)", options: .regularExpression)
let myRSRange = pseudoXML.range(of: "(?<=<rs>)[^.]+(?=</rs>)", options: .regularExpression)
let myORange = pseudoXML.range(of: "(?<=<o>)[^.]+(?=</o>)", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: Thanks Kalyani.  Your answer got me moving in the right direction.  It does work if there's a decimal in the number.  However, there may or may not be.  But I took your comment and did some further research.  For the myDRange, the regex should be "(?<=<d>)([0-9,\\.,0-9])*+(?=</d>)" which will return the numbers between the <d> and </d> tags whether or not there's a decimal.